# Video Player for flutter macOS and windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, video-player

I am building an MacOS and windows application using flutter,I had to embed video player and play a video player from assets. Received an error that the plugin does not support the operating system .
Anyone worked on the video player please help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could try media kit, which now has support for desktop platforms.

[media_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/media_kit) is a new (at time of writing) library that aims to support video across all devices. It's a complete video & audio playback library for Flutter & Dart.
"Performant, stable, feature-proof & modular."

https://pub.dev/packages/media_kit

Answer (score 0):

Video Player doesn't support macOS. There is another package with macOS implementation, you can try it. https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_macos

Answer (score 0):

Dart_VLC is a media player plugin which supports Windows and Linux.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).